# Объявление и инициализация множества однотипных объектов

Tags: java, android-studio

Пишу в Android Studio. В проекте есть 100 кружков, каждый из которых добавлен отдельным объектом ImageButton (Дайте знать, если нужно было добавлять как-то иначе):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из некоторых уроков узнал, что каждый объект нужно объявлять в main.java
То есть понимаете, да, это 100 строчек.Ну и соответственно ещё 100 строк, для того, чтобы соединить это с нужными ID:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, знаю, что это можно объединить в 100 разных строк, типо 
`ImageButton Round0 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Round0);`
но это не сильно улучшает ситуацию.

Можно ли объявить их все какой-то функцией, например циклом?
Если можно - покажите, пожалуйста, с примером.

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Нужно хранить объекты в массиве

Comment: Я догадывалась, что так нужно, но как их запихнуть в массив?

Comment: Объявить одной строкой это объявить массив, а инициализировать ссылки на кружки в массиве нужно с помощью цикла и LinearLayout.getChildAt

Comment: Можешь, пожалуйста, показать прям наглядным примером?
Пример кода, который можно чуток подправить под свои нужды и всё.

Comment: Начало component tree покажи

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/b3C04

Comment: Надо для vertical linearlayout имя задать

Comment: Если ты имеешь ввиду ID - то теперь оно называется "Rounds"
https://imgur.com/a/KTNpw